# Default type in Java Generics, if none specified

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand why the following happens with Java Generics if no type is specified. Let's say we have a simple class:

```
public class NumberList<T extends Number> extends ArrayList<T> {        
}
```

Then, this works fine:

```
NumberList<Number> list = new NumberList<Number>();
list.add(5d);
list.add(2f);
for (Number n: list) {
  System.out.println(n);
}
```

But, if I don't specify the type, it doesn't.

```
NumberList list = new NumberList();
list.add(5d);
list.add(2f);
for (Number n: list) { // Error: Change type of n to Object
  System.out.println(n);
}
```

Why the list iterator now returns Objects? Shouldn't it somehow default to the 'lowest' class (Number)? Can I force it to do that if nothing is specified?

Comment: `x instanceof Object` is true for any class. I would guess the type signature is similar (if not completely equivalent to) `<Object>`

Answer (score 4):

`NumberList` is a raw type. Raw types should not be used and are only still allowed for compatibility with code written before generics were introduced into the language.

Raw types work by replacing all types in method arguments and return types by their *erasure*. If `T extends Number`, the erasure of `T` is `Number`, but crucially all type information in `<>` is simply ignored by the erasure process. In this case, `list` acts as if `iterator()` returns plain old `Iterator` rather than `Iterator<T>` (remember that an enhanced `for` loop is really just syntactic sugar for using an `Iterator`).

Interestingly, the following does compile:

```
NumberList list = new NumberList();
list.add(5);
Number a = m.get(0);
```

This is because `get` returns `T` and the erasure of `T` is `Number`. You might expect that if if `T` is treated as `Number`, then `Iterator<T>` ought to get treated as `Iterator<Number>`, but since we are simply advised to never use raw types, it made sense to keep the rules as simple as possible (even if they are a little strange).

The standard question on this topic is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3973077).

Answer (score 1):

`NumberList` is a raw type, and raw types are contagious. If you reference a raw type, then *all* of its methods also work on raw types.

In particular, that means that the `Iterator<T> iterator()` method that the for loop relies on (based on NumberList being Iterable) is becomes `Iterator iterator()` — it returns a raw Iterator type. And the erasure for Iterable is Object, not Number.

In other words, think about how this looks from the `for`'s perspective. With generics:

```
Iterable<Number> implicitIterable = list;
for (Number n: implicitIterable) ...
```

With raw types:

```
Iterable implicitIterable = list;
for (Number n: implicitIterable) ... // error! implicitIterable.next()
                                     // returns Object, not Number
```

Comment: Plus one for use of the word contagious. It's definitely the best way to put it I've seen.